# int() от большого числа не правильно работает

Tags: python, int

В интернете не нашел этого. Может где-то и есть, но меня заинтересовал следующий вопрос:
Почему при вызове `print(int(123456789123456789.0))` в питоне выводит `123456789123456784`. Почему?

Причем это начинается с 18 знаков. Кто знает, почему так?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235122/how-to-convert-large-float-values-to-int - смотрите второй ответ

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть вам уже пояснили, вот иллюстрация с вариантами решения проблемы:

```py
x = 123456789123456789.0
print(f'{x:.0f}')

x = 123456789123456789
print(x)

import numpy as np

x = np.float128('123456789123456789.0')
print(x)

from decimal import Decimal

x = Decimal('123456789123456789.0')
print(x)
```

Вывод:

```
123456789123456784
123456789123456789
1.23456789123456789e+17
123456789123456789.0
```

Таким образом, встроенный `float` питона изначально не способен такую точность поддерживать. Варианты решения проблемы:

- использовать изначально `int`
- использовать `numpy.float128` (и передать ему строку)
- использовать `decimai.Decimal` (и передать ему строку)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема не в `int()`, а в том, что значения с плавающей запятой двойной точности имеют точность от 15 до 16 цифр. А для представления моего числа требуется 18. Поэтому число округляется до ближайшего представимого значения. Поэтому `int()` уже не может ничего сделать, точность потеряна.

**свободный перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235122/how-to-convert-large-float-values-to-int (2ой)*

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html - здесь как раз объясняется вся теория